# Angular Bootstrap Prettyprint directive not being invoked

Tags: angularjs, pretty-print

Does anyone have experience using the angular-bootstrap-prettify.js prettyprint directive? I am having problems geting this to work.
Here is my Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/mjxNV/

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <pre class="prettyprint linenums">
            <code class="lang-html">
                &lt;div class=&quot;container&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;div class=&quot;left_column&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;span&gt;Small Text&lt;/span&gt;
                    &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;div class=&quot;r_ightcolumn2&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;span&gt;Small Text&lt;/span&gt;
                    &lt;/div&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
            </code>
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code is displayed but it never goes through the prettyprint tokenization. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: need to create module and inject external directive as dependency

Answer (score 0):

I found a sample and modify as your sample:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope) { });

ap.directive('prettyprint', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.html(prettyPrintOne(element.html(),'',true));
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yAv4f/210/